# Regex help - match any file ending with [0-9].jpg

Tags: regex

How do i write a regex to match anything ending with a number, then .jpg.

E.g:

```
10021321.jpg MATCH
1231.jpg MATCH
xxx.jpg NO MATCH
123123-resized.jpg NO MATCH
```

Comment: The funny thing is that a somewhat correct regex is in your question title: `[0-9]\.jpg` will do the trick, you just have to escape `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^.*[0-9]\.jpg$
```

will do this. This allows *any* characters before the final number + `.jpg`.

Edit: Since you only want to allow numbers and nothing else in the filename, use

```
^[0-9]+\.jpg$
```

(but this is not what you're actually asking in your question).

Comment: not characters, only numbers. e.g 10101.jpg not sdfdsf123.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex for this.

```
^\d+?\.jpg$
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the dot.

Comment: @Tim, somehow code sample tag was not applied to regex part thats why dot was not escaped..

Comment: You need a `+` after the `\d` too, otherwise that will only match names with a single digit.

Comment: @elmugrat: Not necessarily. If the regex is just used for validation, it will return True (even if it doesn't match the entire filename).

Comment: @elmugrat,read the question once again. @RPM1984 wants anything ending with number then dot and then jpg. So it doesn't matter how many digits are present. Only one digit is sufficient to satisfy his criteria.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker:  Yes, but the OP wants to only match number filenames.  Without the `+`, filenames like `blah2.jpg` will slip through.

Comment: @Shekhar:  See the OP's comment on @Tim Pietzcker's answer.

Comment: @Shekhar:  `not characters, only numbers. e.g 10101.jpg not sdfdsf123.jpg – RPM1984 17 mins ago`.  The OP didn't word it that way in the question though.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:  `^\w*?\d+\.jpg$`

Edited answer based on comments:

`^\d+\.jpg$`

Comment: That fails on many valid filenames. They can contain a lot more than alphanumerics...

Comment: Mm true.  `.*?` would be better.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow only numbers (according to your comment) then do this

```
^\d+\.jpg$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u7b2)

`^` matches the start of the string

`$` matches the end of the string

`\d` is a digit, some regex engines don't use this then replace just with `[0-9]`

`+` is one or more times

`\.` the dot needs to be escaped to match literally otherwise it will match any character

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is:

```
^\d+\.jpg$
```

or, if you allow non-numeric characters before the number, then:

```
^.*\d+\.jpg$
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore case variant: `(?i)\d\.jpg$`. If you need to match all string, use this: `(?i).*?\d\.jpg$`